# How can one interpret Slutsky's Theorem when formulated using expectations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In a book on probability, I saw the following formulation of Slutsky's Theorem:

Suppose $X_n \overset{D}\to X$ and $Y_n \overset{D}\to c$, where $D$ denotes convergence in distribution or law, and $c$ is a constant. Then $(X_n, Y_n) \overset{D}\to (X,c)$, in the sense that $E(h(X_n, Y_n)) \to E(h(X,c))$ for all bounded continuous functions $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Here, it doesnt make it exactly clear why expectations are used, other than the fact that the normal definition of Slutsky's Theorem may be obtained by setting $h(x,y) = h(x+y)$, etc. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: The statement with the expectations is just one of the definitions of convergence in distribution. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties) for more info.

Comment: Moreover, the statement $(X_n,Y_n)\stackrel{D}{\to}(X,c)$ is more general than $X_n+Y_n\stackrel{D}{\to}X+c$. The former implies the latter since the function $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is continuous and a continuous mapping theorem holds.